# How to properly craft a LineString CQL for WFS GET filter?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, cql

A helper class I'm working on has to make an occasional requests to a GeoServer.  These can be GET calls and I'd prefer them to be.

These are filtered with CQL.  Here is an example, which is returning the ol' `Could not parse CQL filter list` error.  The programmatically constructed uri looks like this:

```
https://site/geoserver/view/ows?
service=WFS&version=1.1.0&
request=GetFeature&
typename="view:mydbview"&
outputFormat=json&
maxFeatures=500&
cql_filter=INTERSECTS(geometry, LineString((-90 35,-80 35))) AND fieldname1 LIKE 'somevalue%'
```

What I've checked:

- `geometry` holds the geometry in `view:mydbview`
- `fieldname1` does exist

What am I missing?

Willing to do my own homework but complex CQL/ECQL documentation is somewhat slender and I've not found a resource that shows explicitly how elements are to be appended to a URL request.

Comment: typename shouldn't have quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LineStrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) only have one set of brackets, so

```
INTERSECTS(geometry, LineString(-90 35,-80 35))
```

will work. If it was a MultiLineString you would need 2 sets.

Comment: That was it.  In this case I was coercing an ArcGIS-style WKT of a line geometry (which returns as MULTILINESTRING) to a LineString.  Had neglected to remove a set of parentheses.  Thanks!